# Storing data efficiently to save ram usage, without lookup overhead in C#

Tags: c#

Depending on which position my agent is, along with its rotation, I need to determine the distances to a wall. As this function takes a little bit and needs to be called a lot, my idea was to store the distances by discretizing the position x and y as well as the angle.

My function is therefore called as follows:

```
float GetWallDistance(int x, int y, int angle)
{
    return CalcWallDistance(x, y, angle);
}
```

where the x and y range from 0 to 500, and the angle ranges from 0 to 360. My first idea was to store it in a multidimensional array as follows:

Initialize the array somewhere by using `float[,,] saveArray = new float[500, 500, 360];`

```
float GetWallDistance(int x, int y, int angle)
{

    float distance = 0;

    if(saveArray[x, y, angle] == 0)
    {
        distance = CalcWallDistance(x, y, angle);
        saveArray[x, y, angle] = distance;
    }
    else
    {
        distance = saveArray[x, y, angle];
    }

    return distance;

}
```

This tremendously sped up the calculation time but the problem here is that the saveArray takes up quite a big chuck of memory, and the agent will most likely not go through the entire 500 x 500 x 360 search space. A lot of memory is therefore taken up for nothing.

I therefore used a dictionary to store the data much more ram efficiently as follows:

Initialize the dictionary somewhere by using `Dictionary<double, float> saveDictionairy = new Dictionary<double, float>();`

```
float GetWallDistance(int x, int y, int angle)
{
    double key = (double)x * 1000 + (double)y + (double)angle/1000
    float distance = 0;

    if(!saveDictionairy.TryGetValue(key, out distance))
    {
        distance = CalcWallDistance(x, y, angle);
        saveDictionairy.Add(key, distance);
    }

    return distance;
}
```

(I tried using a string as key for the dictionary but it seemed that concatenating the x, y and angle takes up quite some time apparently)

This method is indeed a lot more memory efficient but the lookup time for the dictionary using the keys items increases by a large amount with respect to indexing the multi dimensional array.

Does anyone know a way how to store this data efficiently in a way that is also easy to lookup?

Comment: i'm not sure what you're calculating. But it seems like you could use `System.Numeric.Vector2` (or 3).

Comment: `Dictionary<K,V>` uses an array internally, so I think it uses at least as much memory as the `float[,,]` (maybe even more as it introduces a little overhead).

Comment: Have you looked into sparse array data structures?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow the difference is that the dictionary's internal array will only contain elements which the agent has visited, and not every possible element in the entire 500x500x360 search space.

Comment: @canton7 oh you're right, I only considered the (rare) case in which every element has been visited. Thank you.

Comment: If you only calculate approximate values in steps of 5 and use them, you only got 1/25th of the values. How did you measure _the saveArray takes up quite a big chuck of memory_? How much was it? 500x500x360 is 90.000.000 when ALL values are calculated. and a int int int array should take only 32*3=96bit = 12 byte per value

Comment: Can one position be occupied by more than one agent at different angles?

Comment: Do you really need the total distance or do you only need to know if the player is within certain reach? If you only need to know if it's in reach, you can eliminate most values beforehand (i.e. if x > 450) and only calculate a few ones that may be relevant, therefore further reducing the values you need to calculate

Comment: I'm guessing that the lookup will be filled in in a blocky way, i.e. the agent will visit most positions in a given area, but not visit other areas at all? If so, it might be worth splitting the lookup up, so e.g. you have one lookup for x and y from 0 to 50, another from 50 to 100, etc, and lazily construct these. Also, how likely is it that the agent looks in more than one direction from a given position? If so, you can store the angles bit in an efficient way, e.g. starting off with a single angle, and expanding it into an array if necessary.

Comment: The problem is, there are so many different ways of doing this, and then tweaking it to fit your exact usage patterns, that it's impossible to give a definitive answer. We can give suggestions, but only you can try them out, profile them, analyse them, tweak them, and decide what works.

Comment: @Chrᴉz Yes i could use higher discretization steps but that makes the approximation worse. The array is uses 90.000.000 float values of memory when I initialize it. For the dictionairy that is indeed not the case. 90.000.000 floats is equal to 343 MB. Multiple arrays might be needed if I use multiple level maps. So memory savings are quite crucial for my application.

Comment: @SarveshMishra why should that matter? If 1 agent has calculated the distant at that position in that direction the other agents should just look it up instead of calculate it.

Comment: @canton7 The agent is a car on a race track. I use the distances to the wall as an input for it to drive the track by itself. The track is not at all x y positions and cars will probably not drive backwards. So a lot of angles an positions are therefore never used. An agent looks at several directions every frame around itself.

Comment: @canton7 A sparse matrix might be what I need indeed thanks for that tip!

Comment: @BorisMulder aha, so is there any other coordinate system you can use, which only has valid values which are on the track, taking the definition of the track into account? E.g. considering "distance along the track" as one of the axes?

Comment: @canton7 Sparse matrices use dictionairiess, so actually the dictionairy case I presented is an implementation of storing the data in a sparse way. I could wrap a sparse matrix class around it but it would still keep the lookup overhead that dictionairies have.

Comment: @BorisMulder one implementation uses dictionaries, but there are other implementations as well. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix . There are also the partitioning approaches I mentioned.

Comment: I still do think some form of partitioning is going to be an effective first step. That's a cheap way of cutting out the areas of the map which the agent will never visit.

Comment: @canton7 A coordinate system along the track might be an idea, but I wonder how much overhead I would get transforming back an fourth from the two coordinate systems would introduce. I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @BorisMulder you might already use a coordinate system like that, in order to tell which car is in 1st, 2nd, etc.

Comment: @canton7 Yes I do indeed but the answer below might be easier to implement so I look into that first. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET `Dictionary` uses a fast algorithm but has a fairly high overhead still. I experimented with making it faster a while ago. I found that I could make it 6x faster by deleting things that I did not need and by making other design changes.

For example, `Dictionary` uses the modulo operator to map from hash codes to buckets. `%` is surprisingly slow. It takes, I think, 31 CPU cycles. When I replaced that with `hashCode & bucketCountMask` where the bucket count is a power of two and `bucketCountMask` is `buckets.Length - 1` I immediately realized a big performance gain.

I also deleted support for removing items and the iterator `version` feature. I directly exposed the `slots` array so that callers could directly mutate data in it.

This custom type was a lot faster because it was more specialized to my needs and it's API was a lot more difficult to use.

.NET Code on GitHub contains a `DictionarySlim` type for their internal use. Maybe you can use that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. To take things to the next level, the code dictionairy is also accessed in parallel by different threads. As it is a unity project i found this concurrent dictionairy for unity [link](https://github.com/realtime-framework/unity3d-plugin/blob/master/Messaging/Internal/ConcurrentDictionary.cs). Could you help me out to speed up that dictionairy?

Comment: Concurrent dictionaries tend to have a lot more overhead. Here, you can likely avoid that overhead to a large degree with the following scheme. Each thread has a local unsynchronized dictionary. Writes always go there. Reads test a global and the local dictionary. From time to time you pause all threads and merge the local dictionaries into the global one. Clear the local ones. You could do that once per frame in your game simulation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use that thread safe implementation but modify the code so that you try reading in a completely unsychronized way first. If that "hack" read succeeds you got a very fast read. If it fails you have to go the slow but safe read path and retry. This works because your entries are immutable. Once written the value never changes and does not go away either.

Answer (score 2):

From your current listed options, it seems the matrix approach is your best bet both in terms of performance and memory allocation.

I have run the following benchmarks:

```
        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public void MatrixTest()
        {
            // float[,,] saveArray = new float[501, 501, 361];

            for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y <= 500; y++)
                    for (int angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle++)
                        if (saveArray[x, y, angle] == 0) saveArray[x, y, angle] = 42;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        void IntKeyDictionaryTest()
        {
            // Dictionary<int, float> saveDictionary = new Dictionary<int, float>();

            for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y <= 500; y++)
                    for (int angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle++)
                    {
                        int key = (x << 18) | (y << 9) | (angle);
                        if (!saveDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out float d)) saveDictionary[key] = 42;
                    }
        }
        [Benchmark]
        void DoubleKeyDictionaryTest()
        {
            // Dictionary<double, float> saveDictionary = new Dictionary<double, float>();

            for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x++)
                for (int y = 0; y <= 500; y++)
                    for (int angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle++)
                    {
                        double key = (double)x * 1000 + (double)y + (double)angle / 1000l;
                        if (!saveDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out float d)) saveDictionary[key] = 42;
                    }
        }
```

with following results:

```
                  Method |        Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0/1k Op | Gen 1/1k Op | Gen 2/1k Op | Allocated Memory/Op |
------------------------ |------------:|----------:|----------:|------:|--------:|------------:|------------:|------------:|--------------------:|
              MatrixTest |    727.9 ms |  5.733 ms |  5.363 ms |  1.00 |    0.00 |           - |           - |           - |                   - |
    IntKeyDictionaryTest |  4,682.1 ms | 12.017 ms | 11.241 ms |  6.43 |    0.05 |           - |           - |           - |                   - |
 DoubleKeyDictionaryTest | 12,804.1 ms | 66.425 ms | 62.134 ms | 17.59 |    0.17 |           - |           - |           - |                   - |
```

So I managed to make a more efficient key for your dictionary  knowing the fact that x, y and angle can each be represented on 9 bits => 27bits total which fits in an int.
Anyway from the looks of it, the matrix approach seems to be the winner.

Comment: This was indeed what I noticed when running my code. Still the problem remains that the matrix takes up a big chunk of memory on allocation, while a lot of its entries will not be used. I guess the best way to go is as Canton7 suggested by using the track as reference system with the inputs for the matrix being: 
(a discretised distance along the track, a discretised distance to the middle of the track, a discretised angle).

This would reduce the size of the matrix while keeping the fast lookup speed.